# Using react-ga4 how to send and event to a specific tracker if multiple trackers are used

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics-4, react-ga

I have 2 trackers, however some event I want to send only to tracker 1 (G-0000001)

```
ReactGA.initialize([
    {trackerId: 'G-0000001'},
    {trackerId: 'G-0000002'},
])

ReactGA.event('timeToLoad', { loadTime: 10 });
```

How can I send the 'timeToLoad' event to 'G-0000001' only?